# Capture traffic over https in work area

Tags: wireless-networking, privacy, sniffing, traffic, capture

I'm working in an enterprise. I was wondering when I visit websites that support `https` protocol, is it possible for anyone who accesses network of the enterprise(e.g. Network owner) to capture what traffics I send and receive in those websites(such as `password`, `credential identity` and etc)? For example if I check my `ymail`, `gmail` or my `messengers`(such as `Telegram`, `WhatsApp`), could he/she access my password, mails and messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most things, that depends...

In an enterprise environment, you will likely have some sort of security appliance that your connection will have to use. When your https connection passes that appliance, it is fully possible, that the appliance acts as a man in the middle.

In this case, the appliance will cause a (valid) certificate to be displayed to the client machine while it acutally decrypts the data from the service, does its checks, and then re-encrypts it for the actual endpoint and vice versa.

If that configuration is present, whoever controls that appliance can access any data that is routed through it unencrypted. If the appliances certificates are stored in the endpoint's certificate store, it might not even be noticable by the end user that this is happening without further investigation.

Comment: Good answer. One should ALWAYS assume that the owner of the network you are connecting over is capable of watching ALL of the traffic you send over that network. This is one reason why you don't do personal surfing at work and you don't check your bank accounts while connected to the coffee shop or hotel wifi.

Comment: On most browsers you can check it though before you log in. You have to manually check the certificate though to notice tampering. If it is the original server certificate (which of course you must be able to identify) then the connection is most likely secure. IP however will of course still be visible.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS (TLS) can't hide what IP addresses you're connecting to, or even the domain names of the web servers you're connecting to at those IP addresses. So anyone running a sniffer on your network connection can see what sites you're hitting, unless you're running a VPN or Tor or something.

In some extra-nosey corporate environments, the corporation, when setting up a corporate PC, laptop, tablet, or smartphone to access the corporate network, will install on it a certificate the corporation controls, and will cause the device to trust that corporate certificate like any other root CA certificate. This allows the corporation to do a kind of "man in the middle attack" on all HTTPS traffic those devices send/received by way of the corporation's network, so that they can see the actual contents of your HTTPS traffic, not just the server names and IP addresses.